# How can I make my plots look prettier (including fonts, label, etc )?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to obtain very nice plots for my presentation below is a code that I used to plot

```
clear all 
clc
close all
syms v   
omegat= -2:0.000001:2;

Nt=32;
gainfuc = (1/Nt)*exp(1i*pi*omegat*(Nt-1)/2).*sin(pi*Nt*omegat/2)./sin(pi*omegat/2);
gainfuc(omegat == 0) = 1;
G = (omegat < 2/Nt).*(omegat > -2/Nt);
plot(omegat,abs(gainfuc))
syms t
hold on
grid on
plot(omegat,G,'r')
ylabel('G_t(y)','FontSize',16,'FontWeight','bold')
xlabel('y','FontSize',16,'FontWeight','bold')
```

My question is quite simple, any ideas to make this plot nicer (font, grids, etc...) so that it would look nice in presentations?

**Update** 
I have obtained the following figure after the changes recommended in the answer below [image]

Comment: Need some quantitative explanation of 'nicer' as it's inherently subjective.

Comment: which version of matlab are you using?

Comment: MATLAB 2014 @thewaywewalk

Comment: One advice I can give from previous experience is that you should make everything really really large, save the figure to disk and then shrink it in Paint or something to a size that fits your presentation. For example, Axis labels = 48, lines=8, gridlines=5 or something. People at a distance will not be able to see the plot as it is too small.

Comment: If possible, use Matlab R2014b. That will make it nicer (anti-aliasing, better colors etc)

Comment: I am using R2014a @LuisMendo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Matlab **2014b** a new [**graphic engine got introduced**](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-graphics/), it immediately looks more pretty.

> New default colormap presents data more accurately, making it easier to interpret. New default line colors, fonts, and styles with anti-aliased graphics and fonts improve the clarity and aesthetics of MATLAB visualizations.

In Matlab **2014a** you can also activate the new graphics engine by following these [**instructions**](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update).

In **earlier versions** the hack is may also possible, but I haven't tested it. It is most likely quite buggy. For 2014a I use it for almost a year now and it works like a charm. I couldn't find any differences to the final release of HG2 in 2014b.

---

Make sure that smoothing is set to `'on'`

```
h = gcf;
h.GraphicsSmoothing = 'on'
```

---

[image]

I also used the standard LateX font [**CMU Serif Roman**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/) to spice everything up. Enter this lines at the beginning of your code after installing the fonts (open source).

```
set(0,'defaultAxesFontName', 'CMU Serif Roman')
set(0,'defaultAxesFontSize', 12)
```

---

General recommendations:

- Use vector graphic renders: `set(gcf, 'renderer', 'painters')`
- Specify the resolution when saving your plots, especially for pixel graphics: `print('-dpng','-r600','PeaksSurface')` (still use the vector renderer!)
- The vector format for MS Office is **.emf** and is also supported by Matlab
- May use: `set(gcf,'InvertHardcopy','off')`

Comment: Wow looks much better, but I got the following error Error using set
Vector of handles not permitted for set(h). when I added those two lines, also how did you make the blue color lighter?

Comment: @George you have a faulty code line and you need to activate the nee graphics engine. Follow the links in my answer.

Comment: @George: have a look at **Testing HG2** in the article, there is also a screenshot what to do

Comment: Thanks i saw it, but the article doesnt explain how to open this window i.e the HG2 window

Comment: @George you need to create a shortcut of your matlab exe-file and then right-click and properties

Comment: I will update my question and include a newer figure, I have obtained a different figure under the changes you listed, however my plot stills seems to be not quite exact as yours please check the curve yours is more smooth...

Comment: @George is `h.GraphicsSmoothing = 'on'`? Have you closed all instances of matlab and did you actually open it with the modified shortcut?

Comment: I actually used 2014b found it on my other pc... and its still not smooth

Comment: @George I can't further help you, if you follow all my instructions in my answer and comments it will work. Otherwise you need to do some research. With 2014b and `h = gcf; h.GraphicsSmoothing = 'on'` it will be smooth. And with the hacked 2014a as well! If `h.GraphicsSmoothing = 'off'` I get the same ugly plot as you do.